# How to pronounce the resolution 1280×800 in English?

Tags: pronunciation, punctuation

How do I say "1280 × 800" in English? I'm not sure how to pronounce the "×" between the numbers. I'm talking about screen resolutions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I believe most people say *by* for "×", as in *twelve-eighty by eight hundred*.

Comment: The same pronunciation is used the the phrases 4x4 (four by four - a vehicle with power to all four wheels) and 2x4 (two by four - lumber with a nominal dimension of two by four inches).

Comment: This is justice.

Answer (score 3):

Note that it is also common to refer to screen resolutions as for example WXGA (which corresponds to 1280×800).